# Elements not resizing properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `background-image` set in css whose height is interfering with elements declared above him. Also there are three content regions that are not resizing properly when the screen gets smaller. Everything should stack o top of each other as the screen gets smaller but instead it looks like there is a margin being applied. I was using `%` and  `em` to position things which i think now is a mistake. Can anyone help me fix these issues and recommend a better way to position things so I won't have this problem? I know my CSS is pretty bad but I'm new to it and learning on my own. Here's a link to a codepen session I created.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKYrgj

also how do I resize the font so it scales with its containing element without overlapping as the viewport gets smaller?

Answer (score 2):

for your mission section use following css by removing old I hove this will solve your issues

```
   #mission {
        display: flex;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/97/Sveshtnik_IMG_3782.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 7%;
    color: #005944;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    clear: both;
}
```

instead of `display:flex` `float: left;` also work for you

Comment: thank you. However when I re-size the window i still get a gap between the mission section and the content section above with the red background.

Comment: add     display: flex; will solve your isssue to #mission

Comment: did the trick. Thanks!. But why did it work? Like I said before I'm relatively new to CSS so want to learn why things work and best practices